# Get Class Property List With String Value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class following message. I need get property list from here of runtime with string. For example:

```
var classObject = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("edifactProdat.PRODAT");
var unhTypeNames = classObject.GetType().GetProperty("UNH").GetType().GetProperties();
```

But this code does not return my UNH object properties, it returns all properties.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace edifactProdat
{
    public class PRODAT
    {
        public UNH UNH { get; set; }
        public BGM BGM { get; set; }
        public DTM DTM { get; set; }
        public NAD NAD { get; set; }
    }

    public class UNH
    {
        public string MessageReferenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string MessageTypeIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string MessageTypeVersionNumber { get; set; }
        public string MessageTypeReleaseNumber { get; set; }
        public string ControllingAgency { get; set; }
        public string AssociationAssignedCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class BGM
    {
        public string DocumentMessageNameCoded { get; set; }
        public string CodeListQualifier { get; set; }
        public string CodeListResponsibleAgencyCoded { get; set; }
        public string DocumentMessageNumber { get; set; }
        public string MessageFunctionCoded { get; set; }
    }

    public class DTM
    {
        public string DateTimePeriodQualifier { get; set; }
        public string DateTimePeriod { get; set; }
        public string DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class NAD
    {
        public string PartyQualifier { get; set; }
        public string PartyIdIdentification { get; set; }
        public string CodeListQualifier { get; set; }
        public string CodeListResponsibleAgencyCoded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns all properties of what?

Comment: i wanna get this list  ;  var unhPropList = typeof(UNH).GetProperties(); but i need use dynmaic Class Name like var unhPropList = typeof("stringValue").GetProperties();

Comment: You want `PropertyType` instead of the second `GetType()`.

Answer (score 1):

To get (`public`) properties names of `UMH` class:

```
  String[] propNames = typeof(edifactProdat.PRODAT.UMH)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(property => property.Name)
    .ToArray();
```

note, that you have no need in *creating the instance* (`classObject` in your code) of object of interest.

Answer (score 1):

```
var unhTypes = classObject.GetType().GetProperty("UNH").PropertyType.GetProperties();
```